# How to generate a Join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a products model in my rails app, and with in the products table is a categories column, which is comma separated. I want to create a join table (product_categories) so that the categories are no longer comma separated (making it easier to count etc). Im am planning on joining by id on the product table and have id, product_id and categories on the join table.

Is it best practice to run a migration to create a join table or should I generate a model then run the migration to create the join table?

I am running rails 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either approach can work; this is basically [the difference between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

If you need to interact with the join itself as a model (e.g. put validations on it, add additional metadata, etc.) then you should generate a model for the join, and define the relationship as has_many :through.

However, in your case, it doesn't seem likely that you'll need to add extra information about a given product-category join, so it may make more sense to just create a migration for the join table and use a has_and_belongs_to_many relation.

Comment: An advantage of the HABTM relationship over has_many :through is for using fixtures. The HABTM relationship lets you specify in the product fixture all the categories the product belongs to. but if you use has_many :through you must specify each relationship between category and product in it's own fixture file.